# What is the evidence that a secondary party primaries candidate can influence the rhetoric of the leader?

Tags: united-states, parties, president

In the West Wing ([Manchester Part II](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=47)) we see Jed say about his running for the Presidency:

> BARTLET:  I got in it polling in the single digits. Hoynes had it locked up. I got in it to give some speeches and keep him honest...

In the West Wing ([Red Mass](http://www.westwingtranscripts.com/search.php?flag=getTranscript&id=71)) we see Stackhouse (running as a third party candidate for the President) say:

> STACKHOUSE: I got in it to raise issues.

What we see is in the 2016 Democratic primary race is a secondary Candidate, [Bernie Sanders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernie_Sanders), [have an influence](http://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/dem-primaries/270308-sanders-clinton-progressive-rhetoric-hastily-adopted) [on the rhetoric of the](http://www.nytimes.com/politics/first-draft/2016/02/22/bernie-sanders-accuses-hillary-clinton-of-copying-his-message/?_r=0) leader, [Hillary Clinton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillary_Clinton).

My question is: **What is the evidence that a secondary party primaries candidate can influence the rhetoric of the leader?**

Comment: By a *secondary party primaries candidate* you mean a candidate who is second in delegate count and/or opinion polls?

Comment: Correct - the #2 candidate